# Best way to create a generic handler for all return types in c#

Tags: c#, oop, generics, design-patterns

I have a bunch of classes and I want to group them functionally leveraging generics.

Below are my interface and classes:

```cs
public interface IMessagePoster<TReceiptType> 
{
    TReceiptType postMessage(Message message);
}

public class FacebookPoster : IMessagePoster<FacebookReturnType> {}
public class TwitterPoster : IMessagePoster<TwitterReturnType> {}
public class InstagramPoster : IMessagePoster<InstagramReturnType> {}
```

I am interested in creating a generic handler class that is able to return the appropriate return type based on the generic type provided.

```cs
public class SocialPostHandler<TSocialType, TPostReturnType>
 where TSocialType: IMessagePoster<TPostReturnType>, new()
{
    public TPostReturnType postMessage(Message message) => new SocialType().postMessage(message);
}
```

When I call it I have to pass in the class type as well as the return type.

```cs
new SocialPostHandler<FacebookPoster, FacebookReturnType>(message);
```

Is there a better way to achieve this generic handler `SocialPostHandler`? Anything that would automatically infer the type somehow would also help. Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot infer only a few generic arguments. Either provide all or none at all. How would you expect the compiler to assume which of the two you provided?

Comment: I feel like the addition of the `SocialPostHandler` is overdoing things. I would stick to just having the `IMessagePoster` implementations.

Comment: Hi, have a look to the strategy pattern : https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy

Comment: the generic type args are inferred from the input. So you don't want to provide the generic args explicitly, you need to somehow design your input to carry that type info. E.g: design some generic version for your `Message` class.